# SignalR connection stops automatically after some time when running from Visual Studio

Tags: signalr

I have a webpage which displays latest set of data in a JqGrid using SignalR. Whenever the data gets modified all the connected clients reloads the jQGrid with updated data.

Everything is working fine but what I have noticed that page stops refreshing the data after some time i.e. after a minute or so. and status bar in the browser keeps running very quickly and almost every second. If I refresh the page by doing F5 then grid starts refreshing the data but stops after sometime.

Further what I have realised that whatever value I am setting in the ReconnectionTimeout parameter my grid is refreshing data for for only that amount of time and then stops.

ReconnctionTimeOut I am setting out as follows:

```
var config = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConfigurationManager>();
            config.ReconnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

In this case my page is refreshing the data for just 60 seconds and then stops. I tried setting it to 0 assuming that it will keep refreshing the page forever but in that case grid refresh atops almost immediately. I am using IE8 browser.Please let me know how can I make this running forever?

---

Stack trace from fiddler--
**Error starts from this request**

```
GET http://localhost.:2629/AlarmPoc/signalr?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=600dda9b-225f-42ef-a8f3-79008bf6faaf&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22YW.AlarmPoC.Web.SignalR.AlarmHub%22%2C%22methods%22%3A%5B%22notification%22%5D%7D%5D&messageId=2&frameId=1
302 Found to /AlarmPoc/signalr/
```

**Response for the above request**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 13:05:00 GMT
Content-Length: 135
Location: /AlarmPoc/signalr/
Connection: Close

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href='/AlarmPoc/signalr/'>here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

**Next Request**

```
GET http://localhost.:2629/AlarmPoc/signalr/
500 Internal Server Error (text/html)
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 13:05:00 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unknown transport.</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/AlarmPoc' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Unknown transport.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown transport.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: Unknown transport.]
   SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +329
   SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +203
   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHost.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context) +433
   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +125
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8967220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +184
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: Unknown transport.
   at SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
   at SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
   at SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHost.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context)
   at SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Comment: SignalR automatically reconnects after the specified reconnect timeout and the default is 110 seconds. If the connection stops altogether then there's some other issue and SignalR retries forever.
Can you run fiddler and try to reproduce the issue (turn Streaming mode on btw)? It's most likely some network device in your network or a bug in SignalR with IE8. Does it repro with other browsers?

Comment: Hi @dflower, this problem is happening when I am running from Visual Studio. From IIS it's working fine. I have tested it on various browsers i.e. IE8/9, Firefox, Chrome and the error is happening in all the browsers when running from VS. I have tracked it using fiddler which is showing that SignalR is encountering an exception. I am updating my question with the stack trace from the fiddler. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using IIS Express or the Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini)?

Comment: @Andy, I am using Cassini(VS2010 with SP1) this is where "Object moved to here error" is getting encountred. On IIS 7.5 it is working fine. Please suggest..

Comment: Can you right-click on your project and choose "Use IIS Express"?

Comment: I can but do you mean to say SignalR does not behave properly with Cassini, please let me know.

Comment: any final solution about it ? full source code sample?